# По какому принципу цикл FOR IN обходит массив?

Tags: javascript

Меня интересует порядок обращения к элементам в массиве с помощью цикла FOR IN. А то есть с какого элемента начинает и каков принцип выборки.

Comment: начиная с числовых полей, далее в порядке добавления полей в объект

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Цикл for...in проходит через перечисляемые свойства объекта, в произвольном порядке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> **for...in** не следует использовать для **Array**, где важен порядок индексов.
>   Индексы массива перечисляемые свойства с целочисленными именами, а в остальном аналогичны объектам. Нет гарантии, что for...in будет возвращать индексы в нужном порядке и вернёт все перечисляемые свойства, включая имеющие нецелочислененные имена и наследуемые

[Вдобавок, порядок обхода зависит от реализации ECMAScript браузером](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

> стандарт ECMAScript оставляет порядок итерации по свойствам объектов на усмотрение реализующей стороны

Для массивов предпочтительней использовать простой **for**

Comment: спасибо за подсказку (ссылку), можете добавить в свой ответ что это зависит от браузера (из вашей ссылки).

Comment: Я сталкивался с тем, что в некоторых фреймфорках то ли length то ли sort и некоторые другие функции попадают в перечисление **for..in**. Поэтому проверяйте что в аргументах.

Comment: @perfect добавил

Comment: @Sublihim засчитал )

Comment: Для того что бы свойство не подадало в перечисление for..in нужно указать что оно неперечисляемое при создании. Я сталкивался что в каких-то версиях jquery функции добавлены так, что они попадают в for-in так же с числами.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка ) о объектах речи не было, мы о массивах сейчас разговариваем )

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка ну не всем же быть умным как утка )

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка , нуу если рассуждать так то и самовар от чайника ничем не отличается...

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка . я понимаю что я в магазине бутылочек и даже согласился бы с вами. но автор этого ответа в первом желтом (утиного цвета) квадратике кое что написал...

Answer (score 6):

#### tl;dr:

Сначала переберутся числовые ключи соответствующие индексам начиная с 0, затем все остальные строковые ключи непосредственно из объекта, затем из прототипа.

---

### [Немного спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/)

---

Для [различных вариантов `for..in`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation) вызывается одна и та же внутренняя функция

```
IterationStatement: for ( LeftHandSideExpression in Expression ) Statement
```

1. Let keyResult be ? **ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation(« », Expression, enumerate)**.
2. Return ? ForIn/OfBodyEvaluation(LeftHandSideExpression, Statement, keyResult, assignment, labelSet).

```
IterationStatement: for ( var ForBinding in Expression ) Statement
```

1. Let keyResult be ? **ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation(« », Expression, enumerate)**.
2. Return ? ForIn/OfBodyEvaluation(ForBinding, Statement, keyResult, varBinding, labelSet).

```
IterationStatement: for ( ForDeclaration in Expression ) Statement
```

1. Let keyResult be the result of performing ? **ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation(BoundNames of ForDeclaration, Expression, enumerate)**.
2. Return ? ForIn/OfBodyEvaluation(ForDeclaration, Statement, keyResult, lexicalBinding, labelSet).

Если перейти к [этой функции](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofheadevaluation-tdznames-expr-iterationkind) можно найти алгоритм, который определяет получение свойств. Интересен пункт 6

> 6. Если *iterationKind* is **enumerate**, то
>
>    1. Если `exprValue.[[Value]]` равен `null` или `undefined`, тогда
>
>       - Вернуть `Completion{[[Type]]: break, [[Value]]: empty, [[Target]]: empty}`.
>    2. Пусть **obj** будет `ToObject(exprValue)`.
>    3. Вернуть ***EnumerateObjectProperties(obj)***.

Именно в функции [***EnumerateObjectProperties(obj)***](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-enumerate-object-properties) и осуществляется перебор.

В ее описании можно найти следующий пункт:

> Возвращает объект итератора проходящего по всем **Строковым** ключам перебираемых свойств объекта O. Механика и порядок перечисления свойств не определен, но должен соответствовать правилам указанным ниже.

В нашем случае интересны следующие правила:

> 1. The enumerable property names of prototype objects must be obtained by invoking EnumerateObjectProperties passing the prototype object as the argument.
> 2. EnumerateObjectProperties must obtain the own property keys of the target object by calling its [[OwnPropertyKeys]] internal method.

> 1. Имена перечисляемых свойств прототипа должны быть получены вызовом *EnumerateObjectProperties* с передачей ей прототипа текущего объекта как аргумента.
> 2. *EnumerateObjectProperties* должен получить собственный имена свойств целевого объекта с помощью вызова внутреннего метода *[[OwnPropertyKeys]]*

И наконец, пришли к главному: [***[[OwnPropertyKeys]]***](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys). Если объект не строка или [TypedArray](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-typedarray-objects) вызывается [***OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys (O)***](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) в которой выполняются следующие шаги:

> 1. *keys* = new empty *List*.
> 2. Для каждого свойства *P*, из объекта *O*, которое является целым числом больше либо равным 0, в порядке возрастания:
>
>    1. Добавить *P* в конец *keys*.
> 3. Для каждого свойства *P*, из объекта *O*, которое является Строкой, но не целым числом больше либо равным 0, в порядке создания свойств
>
>    1. Добавить *P* в конец *keys*.
> 4. Для каждого свойства *P*, из объекта *O*, имеющего тип *Symbol*, в порядке создания
>
>    1. Добавить *P* в конец *keys*.
> 5. Вернуть *keys*.

В итоге в тело `for..in` попадет сначала целочисленные ключи больше либо равные 0 в порядке возрастания, затем строковые, которые не могут быть представлены целым числом больше либо равным 0, в порядке добавления в объект. А так же после этого в том же порядке добавятся перечисляемые свойства из прототипа.

---

Можно отметить, что поведение массива, в данном случае ничем не отличается от поведения обычного объекта.

Comment: не хочется придется, все хорошо, только вот тег hr в конце очень пугает. Т.е начало такое: массив от объекта отличается тем то, а в конце написано но разницы никакой между массивом и объектом нет..

Comment: @perfect, а где написано что _массив от объекта отличается тем то_? Собственно в ответе всего два абзаца в котором упоминаются массивы и объекты, и только в одном ключе

Comment: Если в массив не добавлялись пользовательские свойства разницы в обходе между циклом for по индексам с 0 до length и for..in - не будет

Comment: @Grundy, Во, я до "механика перечисления свойств" не определена добрался, а дальше разбираться не стал решив что это по-прежнему implementation-dependent

Comment: @perfect, ну так правильно :-) перечитай еще раз о чем речь идет :) **обход for по индексам** и **обход for..in**. По умолчанию в массиве нет строковых ключей, поэтому результат одинаковый, но никто не запрещает добавить строковые ключи, либо сделать в массиве дырку, и в этом случае поведение уже будет отличаться. Тут кстати объект вообще не упоминается

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, ну там как раз в том же предложении - но должна правилам соответствовать. И плюс пример реализации метода enumerate, который удовлетворяет правилам

Comment: @Grundy эта строка говорит мне о том что если я добавлю пользовательские свойства я получу отличный результат. потому что так себя ведет именно объект, вот эту разницу я и вижу.

Comment: @Grundy, ага, ну вот я в эти два абзаца и не вник) Чтение спеки дело такое, для него настроение нужно) (Тем более что в предыдущей спеке порядок таки не определялся)

Comment: @perfect, переписал первый абзац, он вообще к вопросу не относился на самом деле :)

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, предыдущая это какая? начиная с ecma2015 - такое упоминается уже.

Comment: @Grundy не не, давай по существу, индекса 0 может и не быть, порядок обработки числовых индексов может быть разным, плюс с какого строкового индекса начнется продолжение после обработки числовых и какой порядок обработки будет (строковых индексов).

Comment: @Grundy про предыдущую я имел в виду до es2015. Я помнил что в es2015 где-то навели порядок с порядком свойств объекта, но как именно не помнил, наткнулся на "зависит от реализации" вот и решил что для for-in не навели, а Вы вот докопались все-таки все ок)

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, а, просто я сейчас ссылки уже на 7 редакцию дал

Comment: @Grundy, ага, вижу