# Реверс обьекта как

Tags: javascript, объекты

Есть объект

```
var obj = {
    3: 3,
    2: 2,
    1: 1
};
```

Когда пытаюсь его вывести для просмотра, то его сортирует по возрастанию ключа.

```
Object {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

Как сделать реверс объекта? Что бы он был как в первончальном виде?

По умолчанию, создавая объект рандомно указывая ключи в виде чисел

```
var obj2 = {5:5, 2:2, 3:3};
```

Интерпретатор как я понимаю, сортирует его по возрастанию. Вот и думал, что может быть какая - то константа есть, или свойство для переопределения...

Comment: а зачем это нужно? какая цель?

Comment: Объект - это неупорядоченная структура по задумке. Нужен порядок - используйте массив. Да, есть некий дефолтный порядок свойств в объекте, но полагаясь на него его мы грубо нарушаем семантику

Comment: Просто понимайте что когда вы делаете var obj = {}, Вы создаете неупорядоченную структуру и на то в каком порядке вы в нее свойства подобавляли - по большому счету всем плевать

Comment: Про то, какой порядок у объекта по факту, здесь уже отвечали, ща найду

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [По какому принципу цикл FOR IN обходит массив?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606082/%d0%9f%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%83-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-for-in-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму разве числовые ключи не выстраиваются по порядку автоматически? не имея при этом char в виде ключей

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, выстраиваются. Еще раз повторюсь, порядок у объекта - есть. Полагаться на него - не стоит. Потому что для упорядоченных структур - есть массивы. Столовым ножом можно шурупы закручивать, но делать этого - не стоит.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму для числовых он определен по-моему совершенно точно и неопределенности там быть не может

Comment: @АлексейШиманский оно для всех определено точно в последней спеке (смотри ответ Гранди в вопросе который я пытаюсь задубликатить). Дело не в неопределенности (по крайней мере для современных браузеров и движков), а в семантике.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму ну дык `В итоге в тело for..in попадет сначала целочисленные ключи больше либо равные 0 в порядке возрастания, затем строковые...`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я не знаю как мне яснее выразиться. Полагаться на порядок - можно, если понимать что делаешь - ничего не сломается. Но коллеги которые увидят это, порой будут презрительно зажимать нос. Так ясно?

Comment: @user190134 обходите это безобразие в обратном порядке и не парьтесь %)

Comment: Вопрос был как сделать реверс, и возможно ли это не придумывая костыли, а вы тут завернули уже :) Спасибо за ответы

Comment: @user190134, не придумывая костыли - это заведите массив (Array) а не объект (Object). И реверсите его сколько хотите методом reverse(). То я и хотел сказать, костыльна сама задумка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. ES6 устанавливает порядок перебора свойств:

1. Неотрицательные индексы по возрастанию
2. Все остальные строковые ключи в порядке добавления
3. Символы, если они доступны для данного средства перебора

Можно вместо чисел всегда использовать строки:

```
var obj = {
  _3: 3,
  _2: 2,
  _1: 1
};
```