# Добавление элемента объекта после определенного индекса (splice() для объектов)

Tags: javascript

Есть объект:

```js
var g = {a:"foo",b:"bar"}
console.log(g)
```

Необходимо вставить новый элемент между двумя существующими `а` и `b` (После элемента с известным ключом):

```
{
  "a": "foo",
  "x": "xxx",
  "b": "bar"
}
```

Как это сделать? Можно ли это сделать не перебирая весь объект?

Comment: а зачем такое может понадобиться? почему не использовать массив вместо объекта?

Comment: @Grundy чтобы иметь ассоциативный массив.

Comment: В js нет, ассоциативных массивов :-)

Comment: Собственно, главный вопрос такой: в каком месте, тебе важен порядок ключей? как ты по ним проходишь?

Comment: Мне важен порядок ключей и их названия. Поэтому я использую объекты. Были бы ассоциативные массивы, использовал бы их, разумеется.

Comment: Мне важен порядок ключей и их названия. - "Здесь какая-то тайна!" Алексей Толстой "Золотой Ключик"

Comment: @Grundy > _как ты по ним проходишь?_ Например, [так](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) или [так](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). Вопрос не в этом

Comment: @Crantisz, именно в этом. Самому объекту не важен порядок. Для доступа к свойствам порядок так же не важен. Самый просто путь, хранить массив с ключами, в нужном порядке

Comment: @Grundy  
В каком месте дубликат?

Comment: @Crantisz, так как проблема именно с порядком обхода свойств объекта, в вопросе-дубликате описано по какому принципу происходит обход.

Comment: @Grundy и как это решает проблему? Допустим ответ здесь решает проблему, пусть и костыльно.

Comment: @Crantisz, так проблемы и нет

Comment: @Grundy Не было бы проблемы -  не спрашивал. Есть разница между вопросами "Как поменять 2 книги местами" и "Как библиотекарь перебирает книги"?

Comment: @Crantisz, конечно нет, если ты не видишь, как книги стоят на полке, и можешь только попросить библиотекаря перечислить, что есть в наличии, а уж зная, как именно он перечислят, легко определить, что надо сделать, чтобы он перечислял в нужном порядке

Comment: @Grundy возможно, кому-то легко придумать что нужно сделать, обладая знанием из другого вопроса. Однако, это не означает что эти вопросы - дубликаты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS не гарантирует сохранение порядка свойств в объекте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

для Ваших целей  бы воспользовался следующей конструкцией

```
{
  fields: ['a', 'x', 'b'],
  values: ['foo', 'xxx', 'bar']
}
```

Со всеми вытекающими преимуществами.

Comment: ответ немного устарел :-)

Comment: @Grundy уже сохраняет порядок?

Comment: [Не совсем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606163/186999)

Comment: @Grundy окей, идея вынести ключи и значения в отдельные масивы плоха? потому как она мной эксплуатируется для решения подобных задач. Плюс если `values` сделать такой конструкцией `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] то можно хранить несколько обьектов с одинаковыми полями но разными значениями

Comment: не, хранить порядок ключей в массиве - это, наверное, единственный способ гарантировать его при обходе. Устарел, я имел ввиду английский ответ, там речь еще про 3 версию стандарта