# Узнать значение параметра объекта, не зная названия параметра. JS

Tags: javascript

Каким образом можно получить параметр объекта, включая его содержимое, не зная точного названия параметра. То есть чтобы не писать t.body, а писать t[0]. Вроде такого. Чтобы функция была масштабируема и не зависела от названия параметра

```js
    function opr(obj) {
        console.log(obj[0]);
        console.log(obj[0][0]);
        console.log(obj[1]);
        console.log(obj[1][0]);
    }
    var t = {
        body: [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ],
        news: [
            'e',
            'r',
            't',
        ]
    }
    opr(t);
```

Comment: В общем случае никак, так как ты не знаешь в каком порядке эти поля будут идти в объекте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `Object.keys`

```js
function opr(obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj)
  console.log(obj[keys[0]][1]); // 2
  console.log(obj[keys[1]][2]); // t
}
var t = {
  body: [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  news: [
    'e',
    'r',
    't',
  ]
}
opr(t);
```

**Однако**, ключи объекта **не** являются упорядоченными. Нет гарантии, что вы получите их в том порядке, в котором ожидаете.

```js
function opr(obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj)
  console.log(obj[keys[0]]); // 2!
  console.log(obj[keys[1]]); // first!
}
opr({
 first: "first",
 "2": 2 
});
```

*Причём, даже если Вы думаете, что знаете, как сортируются ключи в конкретной реализации движка JS - поведение не специфицировано, а стало быть имеет полное право измениться в следующем же обновлении.*

Comment: проблемы начнутся, если по `0` индексу он всегда захочет видеть `body`, а это нельзя гарантировать

Comment: Так я ж уже это написал))

Comment: У меня ответ еще не был обновлен, в момент написания комментария :) добавь пример вызова своей функции `opr` с объектом `var t = {
news: [
    'e',
    'r',
    't',
  ],
  body: [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}` чтобы продемонстрировать проблему

Comment: Слишком синтетически получается, вот думаю как-нибудь десериализацией проиллюстрировать...

Comment: @Grundy, вроде с числовыми ключами пересортировывает, добавил

Comment: Не то чтобы пересортировывает, просто выводит _сначала_ числовые ключи, которые могут быть целочисленными индексами, а затем все остальным в порядке добавления. То есть с ключом `-1` фокус бы уже не удался :) Во, кстати, [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606163/186999) :)

Comment: Т.е. спецификация всё-таки есть, и в последнем абзаце я прогнал?

Comment: Не совсем, о том как в принципе хранятся ключи в спецификации ничего нет. Есть только про правила обхода, и то там где-то была приписка, что может зависеть от реализации. Ну и собственно ключи **не** сортируются. Они лежат именно так как добавили, с небольшим исключением для целочисленных ключей