# javascript: определить следующий элемент ассоциативного массива на основании ключа

Tags: javascript

Приветствую

Подскажите как в ассоциативном массиве по ключу получить следующий ключ, при этом без сортировки ключей, а в порядке, как их выдает f`or (var key in array)`

например,

```
var arr = {
  'a': {},
  'test': {},
  '123': {},
}
```

я хочу, что если у меня есть var `key = 'a'`, получить `key = 'test'` и т.д.

**Решение:**

Одно из решений -

1. получить список ключей из массива
2. найди в списке ключей старый ключ
3. взять следующий элемент

Но мне кажется, что такое решение корявое и слишком длинное, можно ли все сделать короче, может есть встроенные средства?

Comment: А речь идет о ES5 или ES6? Ответ будет сильно зависеть от этого.

Comment: @Yaant, 1) чтоб в Chrome свежих работало 2) в IE10+ (но это уже не так важно, но интересно)

Comment: А вы же понимаете, что даже в приведенном примере ключ `123` будет идти первым (раз речь о свежем Хроме, будем считать, что разговор идет об ES6)?

Comment: Ну и плюс к этому, порядок обхода ключей циклом `for (... in ...)`, стандартом не определен. Это значит, что в следующей же версии того же Хрома он имеет полное право измениться.

Comment: @Yaant, ок, тогда уточню - определить следующий элемент в том же порядке, что и for_in определит. Правда тогда можно предложить просто вызвать этот for_in и из него сделать push ключей

Comment: Ну да, поскольку порядок ключей в for ... in не формализован, единственный гарантированный способ узнать этот порядок - это использовать этот цикл.

Comment: @Yaant, уже [формализован](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606163/186999)

Comment: @Grundy А, это хорошо. :) Но я не в курсе, в хромовском V8 (который больше всего интересует автора вопроса) это уже реализовано?

Comment: @Yaant, уже давно. Во всех последних версиях браузеров.

Comment: @Grundy Ну тогда круто. :) Хотя с IE могут возникнуть проблемы :)

Answer (score 0):

По одному ключу получить следующий ключ **невозможно**, так как ключи между собой никак не связаны.

Единственное решение: получить список ключей и на его основе определять.

Максимум что можно сделать - полученный список преобразовать опять в объект, в котором ключами будут *предыдущие* ключи, а значениями - следующие, только будет проблема с определением первого и последнего ключей.

Answer (score -1):

В ассоциативном массиве в принципе нет понятия "следующий ключ". То, что браузер в консоли при показе массива сортирует ключи по алфавиту, это исключительно его добрая воля - надо же в каком-то порядке выводить.

Если вам очень надо, то, как подсказали выше, получите список ключей и работайте с ним. Можете, например, его отсортировать по алфавиту и записать в массив - тогда проблем с определением того, какой из ключей "следующий", не будет. А массив можете записать в сам объект как еще одно свойство.