# Помогите понять пример hasOwnProperty()

Tags: javascript

Читаю книгу по `JavaScript'у`, там такого рода пример:

```js
Object.prototype.keys = function() {
  var keys = [];
  for(var p in this) keys.push(p);
  return keys;
}

var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

if(obj.keys().length == 3) {
  alert(1);
} else {
  alert(2)
}
```

Суть заключается в том, что свойство `length` не работает по какой-то причине корректно и я не могу понять по какой.

Далее дается следующий пример, где добавляют проверку:

```js
Object.prototype.keys = function() {
  var keys = [];
  for(var p in this) 
   if (this.hasOwnProperty(p)) keys.push(p);
  return keys;
}

var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

if(obj.keys().length == 3) {
  alert(1);
} else {
  alert(2)
}
```

Не могу понять, как данная проверка повлияла на результат выполнения.

В моем понимании, во втором примере, идет проверка, унаследовано ли свойство у объекта или нет, и если нет, то оно добавляется в массив с результатами, а если да, то не добавляется. Но в тестовом объекте нет унаследованных свойств, по сути результат один и тот же должен выйти, но это не так. Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: «нет унаследованных свойств» — вообще-то есть, воткните `console.log(p)` в цикл и сами всё увидите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка станет яснее, если вывести результат вызова `keys()`.

```js
Object.prototype.keys = function() {
  var keys = [];
  for (var p in this) keys.push(p);
  return keys;
}

var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

console.log(obj.keys());
```

Как видно, новый метод `keys` так же записывается.

Чтобы он не учитывался, нужно изменить ему модификатор `enumerable` на `false`

Убедиться что оно `true` можно получив [описание свойства](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor), поменять существующее свойство либо создать новое можно с помощью метода [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```js
Object.prototype.keys = function() {
  var keys = [];
  for (var p in this) keys.push(p);
  return keys;
}
var keysProp = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, 'keys');
console.log(keysProp);

keysProp.enumerable = false;

// меняем существующее свойство
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'keys', keysProp);
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

console.log(obj.keys());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: none !important;
}
```

Подробнее про обход с помощью For..in можно увидеть в вопросе: [По какому принципу цикл FOR IN обходит массив?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606082/186999)

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае keys содержит и методы и свойства (3 свойства и сам метод keys), и имеет длину 4.
Во втором случае keys содержит только свойства, и имеет длину 3.