# Получение последнего добавленого ключа в объект | JS

Tags: javascript

Есть объект obj = {}.

В любой точке проекта к нему есть доступ через импорт и он может меняться. Мне нужно знать, как я могу получить последний добавленный ключ в объект? Ключи могут быть как строками, так и числами.

**Примечание**: нужно делать это без использование Object.keys и Object.values.

Comment: с обычным объектом такое невозможно сделать.

Comment: Такое можно организовать, но не напрямую с объектом, а используя какие то прослойки, функции, классы

Comment: @Grundy, а как сформировать объект так, чтобы в нём, к примеру, была функция push, но её нельзя было достать через Object.values и Object.keys. Что-то вроде приватного поля. Подскажи, в какую сторону копать

Comment: @SireIMPACTUS, добавил в ответе два варианта решения. Для того чтобы ключ не учитывался при обходах достаточно установить свойству `enumerable: false`: [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/881703/186999)

Comment: А что делать при добавлении уже существующего ключа?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ничего. Уже существующий ключ не должен учитываться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если допустимы и строковые и числовые ключи - то нет никаких инструментов для определения последнего добавленного. Ни с использованием `Object.keys` и `Object.value`, ни без их использования.

Проблема подробно расписана в вопросе [По какому принципу цикл FOR IN обходит массив?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606163/186999): сначала обходятся целочисленные ключи, потом строковые в порядке добавления.

Таким образом, если добавить ограничение, что ключи могут быть только строками, то есть их нельзя привести к целому числу в интервале от 0 до 2<sup>32</sup>-2, можно воспользоваться обычным циклом `for..in`

```
var lastKey;
for(var key in obj){
    lastKey = key;
}
console.log(lastKey);
```

Однако все сломается, если последним добавится числовой ключ, в этом случае результат будет ошибочным.

В качестве решения есть несколько путей:

1. запретить изменять объект везде кроме одного места, использовать функции для получения объекта, и установки свойства. В этом случае можно сохранять последний ключ при вызове функции добавляющей свойство.
2. воспользоваться [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) и возвращать его, вместо исходного объекта. С помощью хука [`.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/defineProperty) отслеживать изменение свойств в объекте и сохранять последний добавленный ключ.

Comment: Ещё можно использовать Map, но по времени получения ключа будет ничуть не лучше чем перебор в цикле.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а зачем Map? раз нужен последний - достаточно только его и сохранять

Comment: Ну тогда можно убрать ограничение на нечисловые ключи. Хотя конечно железобетонное решение с простым запоминанием последнего ключа проще и понятнее

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а, ты имел ввиду Map вместо обычного объекта?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я понимаю, о чем ты, но у меня объект имел структуру `{ [hash: string]: { [message: number (в будущем переведу на hash)]: MessageData } }`, поэтому добавление новых полей ломало бы мою струкуру. Пришлось расширить часть `{ [message: number (в будущем переведу на hash)]: MessageData }` до самописного объекта, который записывает последнее добавленное сообщение в объект. Перфоманс существенно возрос.

Answer (score -3):

Для получения последнего добавленного ключа в объект без использования Object.keys и Object.values, можно использовать цикл for...in:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  // key - последний добавленный ключ
}
```