# Метод map перебирает массив объектов и сортирует свойства объекта по алфавиту, Почему?

Tags: javascript, объекты, методы, map

Есть такой массив:

```
let data = [{
    url: "https://avilon.ru/upload/iblock/593/593be0e326180e0e406d2b57eff6f6d5.png",
    name: "CHEVROLET",
    id : 1,
    params: {
        status: true,
        progress: "80"
    },
    description : "Be conveyed to users of assistive technologies – such as",
    date : 1422153200637
}]
```

Пропускаю его через эту функцию

```
let changeData = data => {
    data.map(function(item) {
        return item.url = transformUrl(item.url),
               item.name = transformLowerCase(item.name),
               delete item.id,
               item.params = transformParams(item.params.status, item.params.progress),
               item.description = cutString(item.description),
               item.date = transformDate(item.date);

    });

    return data;
};
```

И почему то на выходе свойства объекта сортируется по алфавиту, вот так :

```
{
    date: "2015/1/25 5:33"
    description: "Be conveyed to users of assistive technologies – such as..."
    name: "Chevrolet"
    params: "true => 80"
    url: "https://avilon.ru/upload/iblock/593/593be0e326180e0e406d2b57eff6f6d5.png"
}
```

```js
let data = [{
  url: "https://avilon.ru/upload/iblock/593/593be0e326180e0e406d2b57eff6f6d5.png",
  name: "CHEVROLET",
  id: 1,
  params: {
    status: true,
    progress: "80"
  },
  description: "Be conveyed to users of assistive technologies – such as",
  date: 1422153200637
}];

let changeData = data => {
  data.map(function(item) {
    return item.url = '1', // transformUrl(item.url),
      item.name = '2', // transformLowerCase(item.name),
      delete item.id,
      item.params = '3', // transformParams(item.params.status, item.params.progress),
      item.description = '4', // cutString(item.description),
      item.date = '5'; // transformDate(item.date);

  });

  return data;
};

console.log(data);
console.log(changeData(data));
```

Comment: Не судите строго, я начинающий)

Comment: map тут ни причём. Порядок свойств объекта не определён, то что они по алфавиту это скорее все вам console.log так показал

Comment: Добавил сниппет с примером твоего кода, как можно заметить никакой сортировки свойств не осуществляется.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, формально [определен порядок обхода свойств](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606163/186999)

Comment: @Grundy ну да, «в порядке определения свойств», если это не целое неотрицательное число, да и это определение только для обхода, а console.log это не обход, а какая-то нестандартная функция :)

Comment: @АндрейИзмайлов, в любом случае порядок свойств не примере не поменялся. Вот кстати `console.log` как раз `implementation defined` так что вывод вообще может ни от чего не зависеть :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Порядок свойств не меняется, просто Хром в консоли показывает их по алфавиту, вероятно, для удобства поиска. Если нужно вывести в оригинальном порядке, использую json:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, "  "));
```