# Почему метод Object.fromEntries ведет себя неожиданным способом?

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся со странным поведением метода `Object.fromEntries`

Есть следующий код:

```js
const obj = { 0: 6, 1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 2 };

const res = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
        .map( ([key, value]) => [value, +key] )
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res) === JSON.stringify(obj)); // true

/*
    obj { 0: 6, 1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 2 }
    res { 0: 6, 1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 2 }
*/
```

Только вот объект, ссылка на который находится в переменной `res`, тот-же самый, что и исходный

Может кто-нибудь объяснить что тут происходит? В [спецификации](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.fromentries) про это информации не нашел.
Спасибо!

Comment: Ну правильно. у тебя при смене ключ-значения получается объект с теми же парами, что и в исходном.....что не так?))

Comment: у тебя в исходном объекте есть как пара 6-0 и 0-6.....как 1-7 так и 7-1....... поменяв местами получается тоже самое. а нумерованные ключи в объекте - всегда последовательно идут

Comment: Да, спасибо, я только что это заметил и пришел сюда про это написать)))
Нужно, короче, уже спать идти)

Comment: `var obj3 = { 777: 6, 666: 2, 1: 7  }`  а на выходе будет `{1: 7, 666: 2, 777: 6}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ключи и значения в объекте подобраны так, что при обмене их между собой - список ключей и список значений не меняется.

Фактически, вся проверка зависит от того, каким способом по свойствам проходит `JSON.stringify` при составлении строки.

---

Обратимся к [спецификации](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/structured-data.html#sec-json.stringify): при вызове `JSON.stringify` без параметров `replacer` и `space` все сводится к выполнению внутренней функции [`SerializeJSONProperty`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/structured-data.html#sec-serializejsonproperty) в которую передается текущее состояние, ключ с которого начинается сериализация (пустая строка, аргумент `key`) и объект заглушка (аргумент `holder`) представляющий из себя

```
{
    "": value
}
```

где `value` - это объект переданный в `JSON.stringify`.

В функции [`SerializeJSONProperty`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/structured-data.html#sec-serializejsonproperty), согласно правилам, в случае, если `holder[key]` является объектом выполнение переходит в [`SerializeJSONObject`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/structured-data.html#sec-serializejsonobject)

Здесь, в пункте 5 и 6 определяется порядок обхода свойств. Для случая в вопросе, список свойств не задан, поэтому порядок определяется в функции [`EnumerableOwnPropertyNames`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-enumerableownpropertynames), который составляет список ключей, основываясь на выдаче от [`[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys) (подробнее алгоритм можно увидеть в ответе на вопрос [По какому принципу цикл FOR IN обходит массив?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606163/186999)

Для случая в вопросе: обход производится по числовым ключам в порядке возрастания. Так как список ключей одинаковый, то и результаты также одинаковые.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!